# Bubble Sorting in Scheme

Tags: list, sorting, scheme, bubble-sort

I am writing a recursive code to Bubble Sort (smallest to largest by swapping)
  I have a code to do the bubble sort just once

```
(define (bubble-up L)  
   (if (null? (cdr L))  
     L   
  (if (< (car L) (cadr L))  
(cons (car L) (bubble-up (cdr L)))  
(cons (cadr L) (bubble-up (cons (car L) (cddr L))))  
  )
 )
```

if i put a list into this code, it returns the list with the largest number at the end
EX.. (bubble-up ' (8 9 4 2 6 7)) -> ' (8 4 2 6 7 9)

Now i am trying to write a code to do the (bubble-up L) N times (the number of integers in list)
I have this code:

```
  (define (bubble-sort-aux N L)   
    (cond ((= N 1) (bubble-up L))  
       (else (bubble-sort-aux (- N 1) L)  
  (bubble-up L))))  
(bubble-sort-aux 6 (list 8 9 4 2 6 7))  -> ' (8 4 2 6 7 9)
```

But the recursion doesn't seem to happen because it only sorts once!
Any suggestions would be welcome, i'm just stumped!

Comment: "I am writing a recursive code to Bubble Sort " -  don't!!

Comment: @MitchWheat AveryPoole is writing in Scheme, where tail-call optimization is mandated by the specification.  Iteration is typically achieved through tail-recursion in Scheme.  Recusion _is_ the natural to implement this in Scheme.

Comment: Is there an alternative method? Just started with writing code, tail-recursion is the only way i've learned. @MitchWheat

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: I was referring to using BubbleSort in general.

Comment: Scheme (at least R5RS) supports a `do` iteration construct, but it will be _much_ more common to see tail recursion used to express iteration in Scheme.  For instance, ÓscarLópez's answer is superficially recursive, but because the call to `bubble-sort-aux` is in tail position, it's essentially iterative.  Your `bubble-up` _isn't_ tail recursive, though.  You might consider trying to make it tail recursive, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (bubble-sort-aux N L)   
  (cond ((= N 1) (bubble-up L))  
        (else (bubble-sort-aux (- N 1) (bubble-up L)))))
```

If you keep "bubbling-up" the list `N` times it'll be sorted at the end. The problem with your code is that you weren't using the result of `bubble-up` for anything - but if we pass the value returned by `bubble-up` to the next call of the function, it'll eventually be sorted. Now the procedure works as expected:

```
(bubble-sort-aux 6 (list 8 9 4 2 6 7))
=> '(2 4 6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: thanks a ton Oscar! I think i'm a little burned out, that was kind of a big mistake =/

Answer (score 0):

My implementation:

```
(define (bubble-swap ls)
  (if (null? (cdr ls))
      ls
      (if (> (car ls) (cadr ls))
          (cons (cadr ls) (bubble-swap (cons (car ls) (cddr ls))))
          (cons (car ls) (bubble-swap (cdr ls))))))

(define (len ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      0
      (+ 1 (len (cdr ls)))))

(define (bubblesort_ ls n)
  (if (= n 1)
      ls
      (bubblesort_ (bubble-swap ls) (- n 1))))

(define (bubblesort ls) (bubblesort_ ls (len ls)))
```

I implemented a custom `len` function but you can use standard `length` function, if available.