# Bubble Sorting with Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm working on implementing a bubble sorting algorithm in Scheme, and I must say that the functional way of programming is a strange concept and I am struggling a bit to grasp it.

I've successfully created a function that will bubble up the first largest value we come across, but that's about all it does.

```
(bubbleH '(5 10 9 8 7))
(5 9 8 7 10)
```

I am struggling with the helper function that is required to completely loop through the list until no swaps have been made.

Here's where I am at so far, obviously it is not correct but I think I am on the right track. I know that I could pass in the number of elements in the list myself, but I am looking for a solution different from that.

```
(define bubbaS
  (lambda (lst)
  (cond (( = (length lst) 1) (bubba-help lst))
      (else (bubbaS (bubba-help lst))))))
```

Comment: Share what you have implemented thus far, and call out where you are snagged trying to shape it up further.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bubble Sorting in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260784/bubble-sorting-in-scheme)

Comment: My question is different than what you've linked in that I would not like to pass the number of elements as an argument. I suppose I should've added that in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `bubble-up` and `bubble-sort-aux` implementations in the [possible-duplicate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260784/bubble-sorting-in-scheme) I referenced...

```
(define (bubble-up L)
    (if (null? (cdr L))   
        L    
        (if (< (car L) (cadr L))   
            (cons (car L) (bubble-up (cdr L)))   
            (cons (cadr L) (bubble-up (cons (car L) (cddr L)))))))

(define (bubble-sort-aux N L)    
    (cond ((= N 1) (bubble-up L))   
          (else (bubble-sort-aux (- N 1) (bubble-up L)))))
```

..., this is simple syntactic sugar:

```
(define (bubbleH L) 
    (bubble-sort-aux (length L) L))
```

With the final bit of syntactic sugar added, you should get exactly what you specified in your question:

```
(bubbleH '(5 10 9 8 7))
=> (5 7 8 9 10)
```

You can tinker with everything above in a [repl.it session](http://repl.it/OtI) I saved & shared.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own *tail-recursive* version.

The inner function will bubble up the largest number just like your `bubbleH` procedure. But instead of returning a complete list, it will return 2 values:

- the unsorted 'rest' list
- the largest value that has bubbled up

such as:

```
> (bsort-inner '(5 1 4 2 8))
'(5 2 4 1)
8
> (bsort-inner '(1 5 4 2 8))
'(5 2 4 1)
8
> (bsort-inner '(4 8 2 5))
'(5 2 4)
8
```

Now the outer loop just has to `cons` the second value returned, and iterate on the remaining list.

Code:

```
(define (bsort-inner lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (res null))
    (let ((ca1 (car lst)) (cd1 (cdr lst)))
      (if (null? cd1)
          (values res ca1)
          (let ((ca2 (car cd1)) (cd2 (cdr cd1)))
            (if (<= ca1 ca2)
                (loop cd1 (cons ca1 res))
                (loop (cons ca1 cd2) (cons ca2 res))))))))

(define (bsort lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (res null))
    (if (null? lst)
        res
        (let-values (((ls mx) (bsort-inner lst)))
          (loop ls (cons mx res))))))
```

For a *recursive* version, I prefer one where the *smallest* value bubbles in front:

```
(define (bsort-inner lst)
  ; after one pass, smallest element is in front
  (let ((ca1 (car lst)) (cd1 (cdr lst)))
    (if (null? cd1)
        lst ; just one element => sorted
        (let ((cd (bsort-inner cd1))) ; cd = sorted tail
          (let ((ca2 (car cd)) (cd2 (cdr cd)))
            (if (<= ca1 ca2)
                (cons ca1 cd)
                (cons ca2 (cons ca1 cd2))))))))

(define (bsort lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      null
      (let ((s (bsort-inner lst)))
        (cons (car s) (bsort (cdr s))))))
```